# Enable open directory (folder browsing) .htaccess and httpd.conf

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf

I am running WordPress on an AWS instance. I would like to open up a single directory on my server to allow folder browsing.

I have tried adding an .htaccess file to folder with the line

```
Options +Indexes
```

I have also tried modifying the httpd.conf file in /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf and adding

```
<Directory "/publicFolder">
    Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have tried various combinations of the above options, but nothing seems to work. I have made sure to reboot the AWS instance after updating httpd.conf.

When I try to access the folder, I get a default WordPress page with the message "OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND." It is probably a simple mistake, but this is all new to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Directory` is used for absolute file system paths. Make sure you speficy the whole path instead of just the relative path from documentroot.

Extra Note: Don't mix 2.2 and 2.4 directives. Remove Order/Allow directives.